# Why does a fetch call work on port 3000 when I'm serving from port 8000?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am working through a React tutorial which has the following fetch call:

```
const upvoteArticle = async () => {
    const result = await fetch(`/api/articles/${articleName}/upvote`, {
        method: 'post'
    });
    console.log(result);
    const body = await result.json();
    setArticleInfo(body);
}
```

The code works, i.e. updates my vote counter in my database fine, but I notice when looking at the url that it is using port 3000 while I am serving my API on port 8000:

```
Response { type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/articles/learn-react/upvote", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
```

I notice also in Postman, that both of these URLs work:

`localhost:3000/api/articles/learn-react/upvote`

`localhost:8000/api/articles/learn-react/upvote`

Where is the port being remapped to 3000, and what is the sense of this? For instance, if I wanted to have two APIs running locally, e.g. one on port 8000 and one on port 8001, how would I specify this?

Comment: In the package.json there is a field like below:
`"proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
This enabled proxying requests in development for me.

Comment: To be able to setup multiple addresses for APIs, you can use http-proxy-middleware npm package to set this up...